# blockchain.info API key Error “ Request already present”

Tags: blockchain

I am trying to make API key in my localhost to test API to connect to Wallet. by using this url:

```
https://api.blockchain.info/customer/signup
```

when i entered url (http://localhost) i got this error:

```
Error " Request already present"
```

How can i get API key to use it in my localhost?

also,when i tried to create address using following code:

```
<?php
// Include the autoload.php from its vendor directory
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Create the base Blockchain class instance
$Blockchain = new \Blockchain\Blockchain();

// Needed before calling $Blockchain->Wallet or $Blockchain->Create
$Blockchain->setServiceUrl('http://localhost:3000');
$password="12di439d";
$email="m@m.com";
$label="mylabel";
$Blockchain->Create->create($password, $email=null, $label=null);

?>
```

i got error:
 Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused